# is it possible to load test an web application using cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, load

I have to login with 1k+ users to test the front end. And the other perspective is to test the app to check the endurance of the app that how app reacts to number of users?

Comment: I think you should use Docker & JMeter to run load test using cypress

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your approach and using a load testing tool like [K6](https://k6.io/docs/getting-started/running-k6/) is the right tool for this job.
Start by:

1. Run a test.
2. Add virtual users.
3. Increase the test duration.
4. Ramp the number of requests up and down as the test runs.

```js
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check, sleep } from 'k6';

export const options = {
  stages: [
    { duration: '5m', target: 500 }, // simulate ramp-up of traffic from 1 to 500 users over 5 minutes.
    { duration: '10m', target: 500 }, // stay at 500 users for 10 minutes
    { duration: '5m', target: 0 }, // ramp-down to 0 users
  ],
};

export default function () {
  const res = http.get('https://httpbin.test.k6.io/');
  check(res, { 'status was 200': (r) => r.status == 200 });
  sleep(1);
}
```